# Ajax return 404 even thought the page exist

Tags: ajax, jsp, tomcat

I deployed my project in tomcat and when I try to load my ajax it returns a HTTP Status 404 error even though the file exist in the folder.

```
            function deleteUser(){
            var getID = $("#cboMaintainUserID").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "user-admin-delete.jsp",
                data: {x:getID},
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(json){
                    if(json.res > 0){
                        $("#dialogSuccess").html("<p>Successfully deleted User.</p>");
                        $("#dialogSuccess").dialog("open");
                    }
                }
            });
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Fenzir, please check your server.xml, update the line

```
<Context docBase="projectName" path="/yourPath" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:grid"/>
```

Also check the mapping, the Ajax call must be going through some controller having some annotations like @Path("requestPath").

So my url would become something like below.

url: "/yourPath/requestPath/user-admin-delete.jsp"